# Using AlarmManager to update widgets manually

Tags: android, widget, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

As stated in the Android Dev Guide, if you want a widget to update more often you should use the `AlarmManager` to set alarms that do not wake the device.

In principle: do not use the standard mechanisms provided by the `AppWidgetProvider` class and its easy set up with android:updatePeriodMillis in the xml file.

I am sorry to ask, but the guide just states "use AlarmManager, use `RTC` or `ELAPSED_REALTIME`, ..." but HOW EXACTLY do I send an intent to just update my widget is missing!!!

Could anybody please state the code I need to form the `PendingIntent` that mimics the default behaviour? I don't have a clue how to get the widget ids, which action I should use and so on... Sad the dev guide stops explaining at that point!
What is needed as extras to which action?

In case somebody is interested why I want to update more frequently than 30 minutes: my widget shows when the next bus departs at a station. There is a bus every 20 minutes, so I got two options: update the widget every minute, displaying the departure time of the next bus (that's what I want!!) or, not that good, state the departure time of the next bus so I will have to update at least every 20 minutes!

Now: when the device is asleep, of course, this should never wake it up - so my understanding of this section in the dev guide is that this is the correct way to implement it; anybody thinks I'm wrong?
Oh, another thing I would like to find out: if the device is asleep when the widget should be updated and my alarm is not issued due to the sleeping device, will it be updated IMMEDIATELY when it wakes up???

Thanks for your help!!

PS: I really wonder why the xml definition of a widget provider does not allow to simply state "don't wake the device" by a boolean switch... that would make life so much easier in the first place! What kind of a widget needs to wake device anyhow??? ;-)

This is how far I came up to now, but it does not work - nothing happens:

```
private void startAlarm(Context pContext) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startAlarm");
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    intent.setClass(pContext, getClass());
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(pContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pi);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Could anybody please state the code I need to form the PendingIntent that mimics the default behaviour?

I wouldn't, because AFAIK it is not possible to "mimic the default behavior" precisely. Simply have the `AlarmManager` alarm use a `PendingIntent` that either sends a custom action to your `AppWidgetProvider` that you process in `onReceive()`, or calls `startService()` on the `IntentService` you are using for the real smarts behind your app widget.

> I don't have a clue how to get the widget ids

You saved the widget IDs from actual `onUpdate()` calls, such as when the app widget is first put on the screen. When your alarm goes off, update all your app widgets.

> update the widget every minute, displaying the departure time of the next bus (that's what I want!!)

Please allow this to be user-configurable.

> Oh, another thing I would like to find out: if the device is asleep when the widget should be updated and my alarm is not issued due to the sleeping device, will it be updated IMMEDIATELY when it wakes up???

AFAIK, yes, but I have not used alarms that are not of the `_WAKEUP` variety.

Comment: The big problem is that I don't really get to the point to "remember" the current widget ids. The array of ids that `onUpdate` gets is not always the FULL list; when adding a new widget it even gets called with this single new id BEFORE the configuration dialog is properly ended with "OK" button or sth like that! Why??? Plus, the only way to see widgets getting kicked out is in `onDelete` - but right now it does not work. The provider is instantiated over and over again - should I use preferences to store the known widget ids??

Comment: @Zordid: Then call `getAppWidgetIds()` on `AppWidgetManager`. That won't help you much if you do not know what ID goes with what configuration. Personally, I have not written an app widget for which multiple instances made any sense, so I have settled for just updating all instances with the same content.

Comment: Ahhhh! `getAppWidgetIds()`!! Cool, no example ever showed that anywhere! How did you know?? :-)

Comment: @Zordid: Because I ran into it when answering another SO question. Again, it's not especially useful IMHO -- if you are going to update all app widgets with the same content, you don't need the IDs anyway. And if you are not going to update them with the same content, you needed to know the IDs by some other means, so you have configuration data per ID. But, if it solves some problem for you, enjoy!

Comment: No, it's not the same content - each widget can display a different station's departure time. But as the maximum update interval is once per minute, I can as well update all of them...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if they can still help you but I wrote some posts about Android Widget some days ago.

Here is the one regarding the AlarmManager:

http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/take-your-time-widgets-and-alarmmanager/